# Changing "message" key name in winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I'm using winston for structured logging and I'd like to change the "message" key name in winston to something else like "payload". Is this possible?

e.g.

```
{"message":{"x": 9},"level":"error"}
```

to

```
{"payload":{"x": 9},"level":"error"}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I would be interested in a solution too :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can write a custom formatter like this:

```
const customFormat = winston.format(
  (info, opts = {}) => {
    const { message, level, ...otherProps } = info;
    return { ...otherProps, level, [opts.field || 'payload']: message };
  },
);
```

It renames "message" field to "payload" as default but you can customize expected field name.

In your logger configuration you just need to apply your formatter before JSON formatter, eg.:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'debug' : 'info',
  format: winston.format.combine(
    customFormat({ field: 'content' }),
    winston.format.json(),
  ),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
});

module.exports = logger;
```